# More condense way to combine same elements in array to one string in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, refactoring

I'm trying to learn how to refactor my code, and I have written the following function block:

```
joinSame = (arr) =>{
    let simplifiedArr = [];
    for(let i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
        const tempLast = arr.lastIndexOf(arr[i]);
        const element = arr[i].toString()
        if(i === tempLast){
            simplifiedArr.push(element);
        } else {
            const tempMultiplier = tempLast-i+1;
            simplifiedArr.push(element.repeat(tempMultiplier));
            i = tempLast;
        }
    }
    return simplifiedArr;
}
```

The idea is that if I input a sorted array (`[3,3,3,4,'a','a']`), I want the output to be an array with similar entities combined into a string (`['333', '4', 'aa']`). I tried to use the .map and .forEach array method, but my problem is trying to "hop" the index to go to the next unique element.

Am I overcomplicating things by trying to get it to refactor to a .map or .forEach method, or is my code "good" enough to let it go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `reduce` and then take `Object.values`:

```js
const arr = [3,3,3,4,'a','a'];
const result = Object.values(arr.reduce((a,b)=>(a[b]=(a[b] || '')+b,a),{}))

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought the reduce method only gave one value for the output. Looks like I need to study that one more along with Object.values.